# NULLIF vs IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you explain to me what is the difference between the sql-functions "NULLIF" and "IFNULL"?

Comment: One is equivalent to `COALESCE()`, the other returns `NULL` for a given value.  They really have nothing to do with each other . . . just look at the MySQL documentation to see what each does.

Comment: A quick Google search could give you the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IFNULL(value-to-test, action-if-tested-as-null )

#equivalent case expression:
CASE WHEN value-to-test IS NULL THEN action-if-tested-as-null ELSE value-to-test END
```

`IFNULL` directs the query to output the second parameter if the first paramenetr happens to be NULL, otherwise it outputs the first parameter. `IFNULL` is a MySQL only function name, the SQL standard alternative is `COALESCE`

```
NULLIF(value-to-compare-a, value-to-compare-b )

#equivalent case expression:
CASE WHEN value-to-compare-a = value-to-compare-b THEN null ELSE value-to-compare-a END
```

`NULLIF` compares 2 values. If BOTH values are the SAME then it returns NULL otherwise it returns the first parameter.

Personally I always prefer to use `COALESCE` instead of IFNULL.

Comment: just a short question; if ifnull is comparable to coalesce then if in an ifnull case all parameters are null, it returns nothing,right?

Comment: if both the `val1` and `val2` are NULL then `ifnull(val1,val2)` returns NULL and so would `coalesce(va1,val2)`

Comment: The type of the first argument to NULLIF cannot be the NULL constant because the type of the first argument has to be known.

Comment: When both values evaluate to NULL it returns NULL just as COALESCE does. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c45a6/1

Comment: @NerdsofTechnology *The type of the first argument to NULLIF cannot be the NULL* ?? (have you tried it?) **it is allowed** & because NULL cannot be compared using equal it always returns NULL see http://rextester.com/DVGCA98118